# JQuery DynaTree plugin - how to invoke hyperlink

Tags: jquery, plugins, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I have a link on web page

```
<li data="url: 'www.mypage.com?index.php?CId=2&MId=14&MTId=1'">mylink
```

In my js script
I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#tree").dynatree({
 persist: true,

 onPostInit: function(isReloading, isError) {
        this.reactivate();
 },

 onActivate: function(dtnode) {
        var isInitializing = dtnode.tree.isInitializing(); 
        var isReloading = dtnode.tree.isReloading(); 
        var isUserEvent = dtnode.tree.isUserEvent(); 

       if( dtnode.data.url )
          window.open(dtnode.data.url); 

}   

    });

});
```

What should I do instead of `window.open` so the url reloads in the same window, not opening a new one?
There's no name in the web page where I could use iFrame way.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070484/how-to-make-hyperlinks-in-dynatree-jquery-plugin-clickable/6086484#6086484

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest

```
onActivate: function(node) { 
    if( node.data.href ){
        // use href to change the current frame:
        window.location.href = node.data.href; 
        // or load data into a div tag:
//      $("#div").load(node.data.href);
        // or open href in another target frame:
//      window.open(node.data.href, node.data.target);
    }
}
```

See also here for another example: [How to make hyperlinks in dynaTree jQuery plugin clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070484/how-to-make-hyperlinks-in-dynatree-jquery-plugin-clickable/6086484#6086484)

Answer (score 2):

dynatree now allows you to put anchor tags in the li elements.  So you can simply do:

```
<li><a href="www.mypage.com\index.php?CId=2&MId=14&MTId=1" target="_top">mylink</a>
```

Take a look at the [navigation examples here](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-iframe.html#).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#tree").dynatree({ persist: true,

      onPostInit: function(isReloading, isError) { this.reactivate(); },

      onActivate: function(dtnode) { 
         var isInitializing = dtnode.tree.isInitializing(); 
         var isReloading = dtnode.tree.isReloading(); 
         var isUserEvent = dtnode.tree.isUserEvent();

         if( dtnode.data.url )
            window.location.href = dtnode.data.url; 
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi Felle
I would love to hear from you of an answer of another side-effect issue below.

Comment: Hi Felle

When I execute with Dynatree, I saw the html content it generated 
The html file shows 
<div> 
<span class="ui-dynatree-folder ui-dynatree-expanded ui-dynatree-has- 
children ui-dynatree-lastsib ui-dynatree-exp-el ui-dynatree-ico-ef" 
id="ui-dynatree-id-id3.2"> 
<span class="ui-dynatree-empty"></span> 
<span class="ui-dynatree-expander"></span> 
<span class="ui-dynatree-icon"></span> 
<a href="#" class="ui-dynatree-title">Click Me here</a> 
</span>

Comment: <div><span class="ui-dynatree-document ui-dynatree-lastsib ui-dynatree- 
exp-cl ui-dynatree-ico-c" id="ui-dynatree-id-_8"> 
<span class="ui-dynatree-empty"></span> 
<span class="ui-dynatree-empty"></span> 
<span class="ui-dynatree-connector"></span> 
<span class="ui-dynatree-icon"></span> 
<a href="#" class="ui-dynatree-title">Inside Click Me here</a></span> 
</div>

Comment: Retry

In my current front.tpl file, 
=================== 
<li data="url: '{$obj->mCType[k].link_to_type}'">{$obj->mCMType[k].name} 
<li data="url: '{$obj->mCType[k].link_to_type2}'">{$obj->mCMType[k].name2} 
<li data="url: '{$obj->mCType[k].link_to_type3}'">{$obj->mCMType[k].name3} 
<li data="url: '{$obj->mCType[k].link_to_type4}'">{$obj->mCMType[k].name4} 
When clicking on any of the above, hovering my mouse over them show. 
http://localhost/people/#. 
After clicking and page reloads, the right screen shows correct input.

Comment: But the dyna tree parents folders all expand to show document nodes or all collasped showing only folders. Before dynatree was ever used, it was like this where the href 
contains the whole url string. 
<li><span><a class"selected" href="{$obj- 
>mCType[k].link_to_type}">{$obj->mCMType[k].name}</a></span></li> 

So on clicking the link, the http request contains the whole string 
like this: 
http://localhost/people/index.php?cid=1&tid=5&vid=3 

I also double checked the <head></head> of the file, there's nothing 
wrong there.

Comment: <script src="{$obj->mSiteUrl}test/lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/ 
javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
        <script src="{$obj->mSiteUrl}test/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js" 
type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src='{$obj->mSiteUrl}dynatree-0-5-4/jquery/ 
jquery.cookie.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
        <link href='{$obj->mSiteUrl}dynatree-0-5-4/src/skin/ui.dynatree.css' 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: <script src='{$obj->mSiteUrl}dynatree-0-5-4/src/ 
jquery.dynatree.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{$obj->mSiteUrl}dynatree-0-5-4/ 
script_dynatree.js"></script> 
For sure we need 
url: '{$obj->mCType[k].link_to_type} 
Is there a way to replace # with actual url string inside using dyna 
rules ? 
<li data="url: '{$obj->mCType[k].link_to_type}'">{$obj- 
>mCMType[k].name 

but do I pass another parameter to replace # of href of ui-dynatree- 
title ?

Comment: Even with the change, will it affect the parent nodes since they're 
not hyperlinks to elsewhere but expand/collapse tree.

Answer (score 0):

This is the documented way:

```
onActivate: function(node) {
   if( node.data.href ) {
      window.open(node.data.href, node.data.target);
      return false;
   }
},
```