# Dynatree - How to enable onActivate on <a> tag rather than <span> tag?

Tags: dynatree

[image: Sample Tree]

Based on the sample tree above, I would like to enable the `<a>` tag for the event onActivate rather than `<span>` tag.

I had been using the `onActivate` and `onClick` function based on Dynatree documentation. But whenever I clicked the `span` area, the function still activate the `onActivate` and `onClick`, whenever you click them.

Is there any way to just click the `<a>` tag?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen this? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070484/how-to-make-hyperlinks-in-dynatree-jquery-plugin-clickable/6086484#6086484](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070484/how-to-make-hyperlinks-in-dynatree-jquery-plugin-clickable/6086484#6086484)

Comment: Yes... But it is not the something that I wanted...